# Don't cut bottom panel when JDialog resizes

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, jdialog

When `JDialog` resizes to smaller size it will cut from bottom to top.
But how to make it so bottom will be "higher priority" and JDialog will cut top first and leave bottom uncut.

Before resizing:

[image]

After resize (top panel is OK, but bottom panel is cut):

[image]

In this case I want top panel to be cut and bottom panel be OK

Sources:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DlgTest extends JDialog {
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            DlgTest dialog = new DlgTest();
            dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create the dialog.
     */
    public DlgTest() {
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel top = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        top.add(new JButton("t1"));
        top.add(new JButton("t2"));

        JPanel bottom = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        bottom.add(new JButton("b1"));
        bottom.add(new JButton("b2"));
        mainPanel.add(top, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        mainPanel.add(bottom, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        add(mainPanel);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `CENTER` and `SOUTH` constraints of `BorderLayout` :

```
mainPanel.add(top, BorderLayout.CENTER);
mainPanel.add(bottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

The south part shouldn't be cut.